# installing artoolkit

Tags: ar-pose, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I rosmake artoolkit package I get the following error..

```
  mkdir -p build
  if [ ! -f ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz.md5sum" && false; fi
  `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz build/ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz `awk {'print $1'} ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz.md5sum`
  [rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz to build/ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz...Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 56, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 28, in main
      urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 91, in urlretrieve
      return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 237, in retrieve
      fp = self.open(url, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
      return getattr(self, name)(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 435, in open_https
      h.endheaders(data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
      self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1158, in connect
      self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 344, in wrap_socket
      ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 121, in __init__
      self.do_handshake()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 283, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

The md5sum file that is shown missing is present in artoolkit directory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33883/installing-artoolkit/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-13**:
Note that the script is able to find the md5 file, as it does not echo "Error: Coudn't find...." to the screen. This looks like a failure in downloading the tar file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @piyushk, it's a problem downloading the tar file. Somehow the SSL protocol seems to be a problem:

```
SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

On my PC, it works fine; maybe just try again (it might be that the server had a hiccup). Or just replace "`https://`" by "`http://`" (the file is also served without SSL).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0